# Neo4J cascade save using Spring Data

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4J with Spring Data, I have multiple Nodes that have inter-relationships, I need to save them for the first time.

Do I need to save each node first and them update the relationship and save again? Or there is a way to tell Neo4J to save them all.

For example:

I have a node called Car that has list of Nodes called Wheels.

```
@Node
public class Car {

    public String name;

    @Relationship(type="HAS_WHEEL")
    public <List> wheels;

}

@Node 
public class Wheel{

    public String name;

    @Relationship(type="HAS_CAR")
    public Car car;

}
```

In this case Do I need to save Car and Wheels first, and then update the relation ship with the Car and Wheels returned from the save method?

Or can I just save only Car with the Wheels populated and tell neo4J to cascade the save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only saving the `Car` after you have "attached" the wheel in the Java world, is sufficient.

Spring Data Neo4j will cascade through all reachable entries when persisting the entity.
Theoretically, it would also be possible to save just a `Wheel` because this cascades also the other way around to the `Car` and from there to the other three `Wheels`.

Two notes on the model above:

1. Reflect if you really need the bidirectional mapping. SDN will choose a different query style if there can be circles in the graph from the mapping. And this would be the case for bidirectional relationships.
2. If this is needed, I would use the same relationship type and put something like `@Relationship(type="HAS_WHEEL", direction = Direction.INCOMING)` on the `Car` relationship in the `Wheel` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, my real use case has a deep tree, and I'd like to navigate it starting from any node and direction.

Comment: I can see what you mean here: https://dzone.com//articles/modelling-data-neo4j

Comment: I see that relationships can be traversed in both directions, in that case is no other point on doing bidirectional mappings other than readability (e.g IS_PARENT and IS_CHILD), is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would always stick with one physical relationship, if it really describes the same, in the database. Thought: Can object `A` be related to `B` without `B` also related to `A`? e.g. I can "follow" someone but this person does not need to follow me. In contrast to "HAS_MET" or similar relationships where both nodes are equal "owner" of the relationship.
This would give you the idea how to create relationships in the database.
Another perspective is how to traverse them in your application (Question 2). And this is something you can only answer for yourself.